# Find at least 10 consecutive values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a column `DuchenneMarker` with the values `0` and `1`.
I want to find at least 10 consecutive `1s` and mark them in a new column `DuchenneSmiles` like this:

```
DuchenneMarker DuchenneSmiles
0              0
0              0            
0              0
1              0
1              0
0              0
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1 
1              1
```

I've already tried it with `stats:filter()` and `dplyr::filter()` but it didn't worked.

Is there a function that I should use or a brute-force method?

Comment: The answer is always "use `rle` " :-) .  Maybe not the fastest approach but pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `tidyverse` you could do something like this. It creates a dummy grouping variable `run` for each run of 0s or 1s and removes it at the end.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(run = cumsum(DuchenneMarker != lag(DuchenneMarker, default = 0))) %>% 
  mutate(DuchenneSmiles = 0L + (n() > 9 & DuchenneMarker == 1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-run)

# A tibble: 17 × 2
   DuchenneMarker DuchenneSmiles
            <int>          <int>
 1              0              0
 2              0              0
 3              0              0
 4              1              0
 5              1              0
 6              0              0
 7              1              1
 8              1              1
 9              1              1
10              1              1
11              1              1
12              1              1
13              1              1
14              1              1
15              1              1
16              1              1
17              1              1
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0

df %>%
  group_by(rl_id = consecutive_id(DuchenneMarker)) %>%
  mutate(DuchenneSmiles = +(DuchenneMarker[1] == 1 & n() >= 10)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-rl_id)
```